# How to dynamicly set select value with php/html

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to get make it set default value based on $rad['brukertype'] from the database, this can eighter have the value 1 or 2 but if statement doesn't seem to work

```
 $sql = "select A.*, Br.Type from  Brukere A INNER JOIN Brukertyper Br ON A.Brukertype=Br.Brukertype";
        if ($db) {
            $res = $db->query($sql);
            while ($rad = $res->fetch_assoc()) {


     echo("<td><select name='type'>  <option value='1'"  if ($rad['Brukertype'] == '1') "selected='selected'" > "'Administrator</option> <option value='2'" if ($rad['Brukertype'] == '2') "selected='selected'">"Iskjører</option> </td>");
```

Comment: *"but it doesn't seem to work"* - checking for possible errors on both the PHP and query side? *"doesn't seem to work"* is not much to go on.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. The query is okay, and $rad['brukertype'] fetches the right value, Honestly I think it might be a syntax error, I'm a beginner with php

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I beleve there is an error with the if statement, I just can't wrap my head around what it is, been looking for hours now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line would cause errors. Try this:

```
echo "<td><select name='type'> 
<option value='1'" . ($rad['Brukertype'] == '1' ? "selected='selected'" : '') . " >Administrator</option>
<option value='2'" . ($rad['Brukertype'] == '2' ? "selected='selected'" : '') . " >Iskjører</option>
</td>";
```